# unable to view image preview before uploading

Tags: jquery, html, upload

am using follow code to upload image and display preview before uploading. but am unable to view preview. can some one find me where i made mistake

**HTML**

```
       <form action="#" id="mainpost">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="section postdetails">
                                    <div class="row form-group add-image">
                                        <label class="col-sm-3 label-title">Photos for your ad <span>(This will be your cover photo )</span> </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <h5><i class="flaticon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Select Files to Upload<span>You can add multiple images.</span></h5>
                                            <div class="upload-section">
                                                <label class="upload-image" for="img1" id="preview-img1">
                                                    <input type="file" name="img1" id="img1">
                                                </label>                                        

                                                <label class="upload-image" for="img2" id="preview-img2">
                                                    <input type="file" name="img2" id="upload-image-two">
                                                </label>                                            
                                                <label class="upload-image" for="img3" id="preview-img3">
                                                    <input type="file" name="img3" id="upload-image-three" >
                                                </label>                                        

                                                <label class="upload-image" for="img4" id="preview-img4">
                                                    <input type="file" name="img4" id="upload-imagefour">
                                                </label>
                                            </div>  
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div><!-- section -->
                                </fieldset>
                        </form><!-- form -->
```

**Script**

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                imgId = '#preview-' + $(input).attr('id');
                $(imgId).attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("form#mainform div.upload-image input[type='file']").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
```

Comment: what do you get instead error ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i dont find any error

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Comment: and please mark the answer as correct as it already solved the problem asked in the first attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly 2 mistakes

```
imgId = '#preview-' + $(input).attr('id');
$(imgId).attr('src', e.target.result);
```

First you are trying to assign the `src` attribute to the `label` rather than the `img` tag, `<label class="upload-image" for="img1" id="preview-img1">` you should add an `<img>` tag inside each label after the input and then assign the `src` to that image the `id` you have assigned to the label assign it to the image instead `<img class="upload-image" id="preview-img1" src="" />`.

Then you are selecting the wrong form `form#mainform` and the wrong element `div.upload-image`

```
$("form#mainform div.upload-image input[type='file']")
```

should be like below after suggested changes

```
$("form#mainpost label input[type='file']")
```

then you are selecting the `id` to detect the preview element `imgId = '#preview-' + $(input).attr('id');`  whereas you should pick the `name` attribute so that the relevent preview is shown in against the input see eblow i created a demo

```js
function readURL(input) {
  //console.log('here', input);
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      imgId = '#preview-' + $(input).attr('name');
      //console.log(imgId)
      $(imgId).attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("form#mainpost label input[type='file']").on('change', function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
img.upload-image {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="mainpost">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="section postdetails">
      <div class="row form-group add-image">
        <label class="col-sm-3 label-title">Photos for your ad <span>(This will be your cover photo )</span> </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <h5><i class="flaticon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Select Files to Upload<span>You can add multiple images.</span></h5>
          <div class="upload-section">
            <label for="img1">
            
                                                   <input type="file" name="img1" id="upload-image-one"><img class="upload-image" id="preview-img1" src="" />
                                                </label>

            <label for="img2">
            
                                                    <input type="file" name="img2" id="upload-image-two"><img class="upload-image" id="preview-img2"/>
                                                </label>
            <label classfor="img3">
            
                                                    <input type="file" name="img3" id="upload-image-three" ><img class="upload-image" id="preview-img3"/>
                                                </label>

            <label for="img4">
            
                                                    <input type="file" name="img4" id="upload-image-four"><img id="preview-img4"  class="upload-image" id="preview-img4"/>
                                                </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- section -->
  </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- form -->
```

## `EDIT`

since you dont want or cant change the html you have to manually crate an image element and insert inside the label

```js
function readURL(input) {
  //console.log('here', input);
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      imgId = '#preview-' + $(input).attr('name');
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
      img.setAttribute('class', 'img-preview');
      document.querySelector(imgId).appendChild(img);
      //console.log(imgId)
      //$(imgId).append('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("form#mainpost label input[type='file']").on('change', function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```css
img.img-preview {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="mainpost">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="section postdetails">
      <div class="row form-group add-image">
        <label class="col-sm-3 label-title">Photos for your ad <span>(This will be your cover photo )</span> </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <h5><i class="flaticon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>Select Files to Upload<span>You can add multiple images.</span></h5>
          <div class="upload-section">
            <label class="upload-image" for="img1" id="preview-img1">
                                                    <input type="file" name="img1" id="img1">
                                                </label>

            <label class="upload-image" for="img2" id="preview-img2">
                                                    <input type="file" name="img2" id="upload-image-two">
                                                </label>
            <label class="upload-image" for="img3" id="preview-img3">
                                                    <input type="file" name="img3" id="upload-image-three" >
                                                </label>

            <label class="upload-image" for="img4" id="preview-img4">
                                                    <input type="file" name="img4" id="upload-imagefour">
                                                </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- section -->
  </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- form -->
```

Comment: is there any way, without making any changes to html can it be done

Comment: @sanojlawrence in that case create an image element and insert it on runtime inside the label in the onload

Comment: can you please help me with that. i tried with my code on question and cant

Comment: @sanojlawrence  ok but that wasnt listed anywhere in your question that you cant change the html,

Comment: am sorry weak in english thought mentioned everything

Comment: i get `the global variable 'img' is not declared`

Comment: where do you get this error i dont see any error in the demo you should copy the code correctly @sanojlawrence